# Disable file output of hydra

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

I'm using [hydra](https://hydra.cc) to log hyperparameters of experiments.

```py
@hydra.main(config_name="config", config_path="../conf")
def evaluate_experiment(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg))
    ...
```

Sometimes I want to do a dry run to check something. For this I don't need any saved parameters, so I'm wondering how I can disable the savings to the filesystem completely in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an [enhancement request](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/910) aimed at Hydra 1.1 to support disabling working directory management.
Working directory management is doing many things:

- Creating a working directory for the run
- Changing the working directory to the created dir.

There are other related features:

- Saving log files
- Saving files like config.yaml and hydra.yaml into .hydra in the working directory.

Different features has different ways to disable them:

1. To prevent the creation of a working directory, you can override `hydra.run.dir` to `.`.
2. To prevent saving the files into .hydra, [override `hydra.output_subdir` to null](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/working_directory/#changing-or-disabling-hydras-output-subdir).
3. To prevent the creation of logging files, you can disable logging output of `hydra/hydra_logging` and `hydra/job_logging`, see [this](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/logging/).

A complete example might look like:

```
$ python foo.py hydra.run.dir=. hydra.output_subdir=null hydra/job_logging=disabled hydra/hydra_logging=disabled
```

Note that as always you can also override those config values through your config file.

Answer (score 16):

The answer from Omry Yadan works well if you want to solve this using the CLI. However, you can also add these flags to your config file such that you don't have to type them every time you run your script. If you want to go this route, make sure you add the following items in your root config file:

```yaml
defaults:  
  - _self_  
  - override hydra/hydra_logging: disabled  
  - override hydra/job_logging: disabled  
  
hydra:  
  output_subdir: null  
  run:  
    dir: .
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the clarification. In my particular case, I would like the logging to appear in the terminal but not to create the files. Also, I would like the log to be coloured. The hydra field would be tha same but the defaults will be set as colorlog. Is that correct?

Comment: @J smit , can you explain the meaning of this config?

Comment: `_self_` indicates the order of *this* config when merging multiple configurations. Normaly it is at the end. Putting `_self_` at first position allows that this config can be overwritten by others. `output_subdir: null` disables the creation of the `.hydra` directory. `override hydra/...` states that the config named `hydra...` should be overwritten.